# How do I know when an Azure File Storage share has been deleted?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I'm trying to delete and recreate an Azure Storage file share as a quick way to delete the entire contents.

The problem is that when I try to immediately re-create the new share with the same name as the old previously deleted share it fails (with 409 Conflict) error. If I wait around 30 seconds after deleting it, it works fine. I assume this is because it needs time to free up the share name.

Here's my code:

```
var targetAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(destination.StorageAccountName, destination.Key), true);
var targetClient = targetAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
var targetShare = targetClient.GetShareReference(destination.ShareName);

if (targetShare.Exists()) {
    var ar = targetShare.BeginDelete(null, null);
    targetShare.EndDelete(ar);
}
Thread.Sleep(30000);
targetShare.Create();
```

According to the documentation on MSDN, `EndDelete` is suppose to block until the delete has completed, so why isn't it?

How can I avoid having to wait a fixed amount of time for the delete to complete?

*(I've also tried the synchronous version of this as well, but this does exactly the same)*

**UPDATE**

Trying a few different things, I wanted to see the timings on the call back from BeginDelete using this code:

```
if (targetShare.Exists()) {
    Console.WriteLine($"BeginDelete {DateTime.Now:O}");
    var ar = targetShare.BeginDelete(result => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Callback {DateTime.Now:O}");
    }, null);
    targetShare.EndDelete(ar);

}

try {
    targetShare.Create();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Result:

```
BeginDelete 2017-02-02T17:42:33.5303589+00:00
Callback 2017-02-02T17:42:33.6289211+00:00
The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
```

Comment: Doesn't `EndDelete` stop the delete process? The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfileshare.enddelete.aspx) seem to suggest that.

Comment: No, it returns the result of the delete process.

Comment: No it's not, it's the async result. For the [BeginDelete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn723503.aspx) operation, the first parameter is a callback to tell you when it's finished.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of DeleteIfExists() which I've also tried. But EndDelete doesn't abort the delete... the docs are a bit vague, but it's just suppose to block until the process is complete, same as BeginInvoke/EndInvoke

Comment: So why not pass in a callback to `BeginDelete`?

Comment: Because the callback is fired immediatly, before the delete process has finished.

Comment: So you've tried passing in `new AsyncCallback(YourMethod)`?

Comment: Yes, and `YourMethod` gets called a few milliseconds after BeginDelete()

Comment: How about calling `Delete` instead of `BeginDelete`?

Comment: Yeah, tried that also... same problem, it doesn't block while it deletes the share :(

Comment: For `BeginDelete`, does the `IsCompleted` property of the return help?

Comment: IsCompleted is false to start with, and then true as soon as EndDelete has been called.... but still way before the actual delete has been processed by Azure.

Comment: How about not calling `EndDelete` then? Just wait for `IsCompleted` to be true?

Comment: Just tried that, IsCompleted still gets set to true even if EndDelete doesn't get called. It takes about 100ms before it gets set, which is well before the 30 or so seconds it takes for it to actually delete... thanks for all your ideas though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/delete-share),

> When a share is deleted, a share with the same name cannot be recreated for at least 30 seconds. While the share is being deleted, attempts to recreate a share of the same name will fail with status code 409 (Conflict), with the service returning additional error information indicating that the share is being deleted. All other operations, including operations on any files under the share, will fail with status code 404 (Not Found) while the share is being deleted.

In conclusion, you can only keep retrying Create() in the loop and catch 409 error, until the share is successfully created.